# Roman numeral page numbers for table of contents

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm generating word docs entirely in VBA and am aiming to have roman numeral page numbers for my table of contents and numeric page numbers for the remainder of the document. My table of contents spans multiple pages and is variable in page size.

**How would I achieve roman numeral page numbers for only a table of contents of variable page span?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where to start, try this approach in Word:

- Insert a section break after the table of content pages.
- Turn on the macro recorder
- Format the page numbers in the first section with Roman numerals
- select the next section and unlink it from the previous section
- Format the page numbers in the second section with regular numbers
- Turn off the macro recorder.
- Adjust the code as required.

Answer (score 0):

I also find Word fiddly in this area, so here's some code to show one possible example. The code clears the content of the current document (so don't run it in your existing document!!), then generates a few headings, followed by a table of contents, both of which are then split by a section break. The section break allows different formatting of the page number (roman numerals for the first section, and arabic for the second). Change the for loop up to 100 will demonstrate multiple ToC pages. Might point you in the right direction. Cheers.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PageNumbers()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim myTOC As TableOfContents
    
    ' Delete word document content
    ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Delete
    
    ' Add in some headings for testing
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
    For Counter = 1 To 10
        myRange.InsertAfter "Heading " & Counter
        myRange.Style = WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
        myRange.InsertParagraphAfter
    Next

    ' Add in a page number
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
     .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add _
     PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberLeft, _
     FirstPage:=True
    End With
 
    ' Add in a section break at the start of the document
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
    myRange.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    myRange.InsertParagraphAfter
        
    ' Insert a table of contents (into the first section)
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
    Set myTOC = ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add(myRange, True, 1, 3, False)
   
    ' Format the page number of the first section to have roman numerals
    With ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(1).Footers.Item(1).PageNumbers
        .NumberStyle = wdPageNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .HeadingLevelForChapter = 0
        .IncludeChapterNumber = False
        .ChapterPageSeparator = wdSeparatorHyphen
        .RestartNumberingAtSection = False
        .StartingNumber = 0
    End With

    ' Format the page number of the second section to have arabic numerals
    With ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(2).Footers.Item(1).PageNumbers
        .NumberStyle = wdPageNumberStyleArabic
        .HeadingLevelForChapter = 0
        .IncludeChapterNumber = False
        .ChapterPageSeparator = wdSeparatorHyphen
        .RestartNumberingAtSection = True
        .StartingNumber = 1
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**The Output:**

[image]